# Flask + Celery failing when calling task

Tags: flask, redis, celery

I'm following the Flask+Celery example, My folder structure is:

```
flask-projects
  |- example.py
  |- .venv
```

here is my code which I'm running with **flask --app example run --debug**:

```
from celery import Celery, Task
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
from celery import shared_task
from celery.result import AsyncResult


def celery_init_app(app: Flask) -> Celery:
    class FlaskTask(Task):
        def __call__(self, *args: object, **kwargs: object) -> object:
            with app.app_context():
                return self.run(*args, **kwargs)

    celery_app = Celery(app.name, task_cls=FlaskTask)
    celery_app.config_from_object(app.config["CELERY"])
    celery_app.set_default()
    app.extensions["celery"] = celery_app
    return celery_app

flask_app = Flask(__name__)
flask_app.config.from_mapping(
    CELERY=dict(
        broker_url="redis://localhost",
        result_backend="redis://localhost",
        task_ignore_result=True,
    ),
)
celery_app = celery_init_app(flask_app)


@shared_task(ignore_result=False)
def add_together(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    return a + b

@shared_task(ignore_result=False)
def multiply_together(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    return a * b

@flask_app.route('/add/task')
def add_task():
    result = add_together.delay(1, 10)
    return {"result_id": result.id}

@flask_app.get("/result/<id>")
def task_result(id: str) -> 'dict[str, object]':
    result = AsyncResult(id)
    return {
        "ready": result.ready(),
        "successful": result.successful(),
        "value": result.result if result.ready() else None,
    }
```

I have all this in **example.py** and I'm running Celery with:
`celery -A example worker --loglevel INFO`
Every time I curl the **/add/task** endpoint I get this error in Celery:

```
The delivery info for this task is:
{'exchange': '', 'routing_key': 'celery'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/johnwesonga/projects/python/flask-projects/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 642, in on_task_received
    strategy = strategies[type_]
KeyError: 'flask-projects.example.add_together'
[2023-08-16 11:17:28,777: ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered task of type 'flask-projects.example.add_together'.
The message has been ignored and discarded.
```

When I start Celery I can see a list of all my registered tasks:

```
.> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . example.add_together
  . example.multiply_together
```

What do I need to change?

Comment: It Seams you app are getting `flask-projects.` prepended when called from flask. Please, how are you running the flask app?

Comment: runnning your example here using `FLASK_APP=example.py flask run`. It works

Comment: @iuridiniz I edited the post to add that info but basically **flask-projects** is the folder where my code is in.

Comment: I've copy and paste your example and I'm running it as you are running. It works.

can you post the output os `pip freeze`?

Comment: PRN: https://justpaste.it/img/6d0d4d38ae340bb61b8bf868b7c64561.png

Comment: anyway, you can call the exact task name by using this `result = celery_app.send_task('example.add_together', (1,10))` instead of `result = add_together.delay(1, 10)`. If this fix your application, there's something in you environment that are prepeding your directory name when you call task by the `function.apply` syntax. Let me know if this work. there's something really wrong in your env. Maybe some package version. I don't know yet

Comment: Broken environment, I  set up the same code in a different venv and it worked!